# How to use multiple conditions for regex using ifelse?

Tags: r, regex, data.table

i am trying to extract and replace '?'in the client column if it matches the group = SA with 'AWS' as client instead of '?'. Here '?' can be '?' or '?????' or ??. However it seems not to work. Can someone help on this issue? I am using R

Thanks

```
test[,Client:=ifelse(Group=='SA'&Client==grepl('\\?+',Client,perl = T),'AWS',Client)]
```

sample data

```
client<-c('?','???','????')
GROUP<-c('SA','SA','SA')
df <- melt(data.frame(client,GROUP))
```

final result should look like

```
Client GROUP
AWS     SA
```

Comment: Please rephrase your question by showing sample data for both before _and_ after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are mixing `data.table` syntax with data frames. `data.table` is used like this:

```
DT[i, j, by]
```

To replace values from a subset of a `data.table`, first declare your subset in `i`, then operate on your columns in `j`. You first want to select all rows where `GROUP == "SA"`, then replace one or more `?` by `AWS`, if I understood your problem correctly.

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr)

client<-c('?','???','????')
GROUP<-c('SA','SA','SA')
dt <- data.table(client,GROUP)

dt[GROUP == "SA", client := str_replace(client, "\\?+", "AWS")]
#    client GROUP
# 1:    AWS    SA
# 2:    AWS    SA
# 3:    AWS    SA
```

Comment: I get this error "Error in `[.data.table`(test, GROUP == "SA", `:=`(Client, str_replace(Client,  : 
  i evaluates to a logical vector length 3 but there are 264997 rows. Recycling of logical i is no longer allowed as it hides more bugs than is worth the rare convenience. Explicitly use rep(...,length=.N) if you really need to recycle."

Comment: @A380 Can you print the output from `names(test)`? I suspect you don't have a `GROUP` column in your `data.table`, thus the subset is trying to evaluate `GROUP == "SA"` with the variable `GROUP` of length 3 defined in my example.

Comment: yeah , i had it as 'Group' in my table, Thanks